# c++ definition inheritance scheme

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, friend

the code is probably bad written and I would like to know how it should be done correctly.

Thanks for help

For the following inheritance scheme: A→B→C

a) define classes assuming that class A is to be an abstract class

b) equip all classes with a virtual name method returning the class name

c) add virtual destructors

d) add a global function friend of class A so that it can perform the same function as in point b

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class A {

    public:

    A();
    virtual void name();
    {

        return A;


    }
    friend void ffriend()
    virtual ~A();

};

class B : public A{

    public:

    B();
    virtual void name();
    {

        return B;


    }

    virtual ~B();

};

class C : public B{

    public:

    C();
    virtual void name();
    {

        return C;


    }

    virtual ~C()

};





    friend void ffriend(&A){

        name.A();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code cannot compile and have a lot of syntax error

> b) equip all classes with a virtual name method returning the class name

that means the profile can be

```
virtual const char * name();
```

or

```
virtual const char * name() const;
```

or

```
virtual std::string name();
```

or

```
virtual std::string name() const;
```

but not `virtual void name()`

> a) define classes assuming that class A is to be an abstract class

so at least one method must be abstract, typically in your case this is *name*

> For the following inheritance scheme: A→B→C

probably because I do UML for me the arrows are in the wrong direction, but *A* being abstract very probably *C* inherits *B* which inherits  (realize) *A*

> c) add virtual destructors

that is trivial, but do not forget to implement them, not only to declare them

> d) add a global function friend of class A so that it can perform the same function as in point b

that typically means the function get a reference to *A*, notice in your case the declaration and the definition do not correspond, and the list of parameters `(&A)` is invalid

An example can be :

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    // default contructor is enough
    virtual ~A() {} // c)

    virtual const char * name() const = 0; // a) and b)

    friend const char * ffriend(const A &); // d)
};

const char * ffriend(const A & a)
{
  return a.name(); // or return "A" ?
}


class B : public A {
  public:
    // default contructor is enough
    virtual ~B() {} // c)

    virtual const char * name() const { return "B"; } // b)

};

class C : public B {
  public:
    // default contructor is enough
    virtual ~C() {}

    virtual const char * name() const { return "C"; } // b)
};


int main()
{
  B b;
  C c;

  std::cout << b.name() << ' ' << c.name() << ' ' << ffriend(b) << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
B C B
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

It is not very clear what name the *friend* function has to return, I supposed the real class name but it can be "A" either.

Note also in *A* the method *name* can be *private* to justify the presence of the *friend* method if I can say.